# Kion mi deziru al malsanulo?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kion mi diru al amiko kiu havas malvarmumon? En la angla mi konas "get well". Mi ne sukcesis trovi ion en listoj de salutoj kaj bondeziroj.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Resaniĝu* estas la vorto kiun mi plej ofte legas kaj uzas. Kelkfoje mi legas *resaniĝon*, ofte sole, kelkfoje kun *bonan* aŭ *tujan*.

Answer (score 1):

*Resaniĝu* has been around since the *Ekzercaro* and is even taught in the [Duolingo Course](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/9090738/Resani%C4%9Du-rapide)